# Control Panel Date Picker: Inconsistent Date Format

Tags: plugins, field, datetime

In my plugin I have a datetime field defined in the settings template:

```
{{ forms.dateTimeField({
    label: "Ends at"|t('optimum'),
    instructions: experiment.isNew ?  'Defaults to 30 days from now' : '',
    id: 'endAt',
    name: 'endAt',
    value: experiment.endAt ?? defaultEndAt,
    errors: experiment.getErrors('endAt')
}) }}
```

When I use the picker I get a date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.
This is then sent to the backend and parsed back to a `Carbon` instance.

This is what I'm seeing on my end:

[image]

However, it seems that the date format is not consistent across installations.
As you can see in this [issue](https://github.com/matfish2/craft-optimum/issues/2#issuecomment-1711444522), the user reports that the datepicker populates the date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, which breaks the functionality as the backend is expecting `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

How can I enforce a uniform format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All dates in the control panel are rendered localized as per the logged-in user's "Formatting Locale" user preference, or their "Language" setting if they haven't set a preferred locale.

For users who haven't set a preferred locale *or* language, Craft will fall back to the locale defined in the [`defaultCpLocale` setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#defaultcplocale).

Comment: Thanks! I see now that I should use Craft's own `DateTimeHelper::toDateTime($dateString)` instead of `Carbon`, to get a reliable parsing of the input. This does all the heavy-lifting of figuring out the input format and building a `DateTime` object. See `GraphqlController:464` for an example of how Craft applies the same principle.